# Timer Interrupt Service Routine on a host computer running at a rate of 10 microseconds or faster

Tags: c++, timer, interrupt

I am trying to run the following pseudocode at a rate of 10 microseconds or faster on a host computer (512 mb RAM, Intel 2.5 GHz Pentium 4 processor, etc.) running on a Windows XP operating system:

```
int main(void)
{
    while(1){};
}

Interrupt service routine:
every 10 microseconds, printf("Hello World");
```

I'm aware that there are MFC timers, but they are not functional if the timers need to trigger faster than 1 ms. What would be the easiest method to accomplish what the goals of my pseudocode? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can get that kind of performance out of Windows XP, at least not reliably from userland.  You might have to run your code as a kernel driver, or better yet investigate using a real-time OS like Xenomai instead.

Answer (score -1):

Ignore this - I mis-read micro as milli in the question Sorry:

As you say you are on Windows, the [MultiMedia Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712704%28VS.85%29.aspx) is the way to go.

Or the newer TimerQueue [TimerQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682483%28VS.85%29.aspx)

You *may* be able to get 1ms resolution, depending on your hardware.

Good Luck